# Key Alias is missing in eclipse while signing android APK

Tags: android, android-keystore

I have already created a keystore, signed the apk and published it the Play store as well.

Now I have made some bug fixes, using the same keystore and the password and clicked next in the export android application wizard.

It shows me a drop box for alias name, with no alias name on it. But the same stuff has worked for me yesterday to sign the same project and now it appears empty.

I also tried it on the command line but it says "keystore tampered or password incorrect", but I am very sure the password id is correct and so is the keystore.

This is a show stopper for me. Please help!

Answer (score 8):

First you should check if you really typed the correct password. 
If you type the wrong keystore password when doing a signed export in Eclipse then the alias dropdown list in Eclipse will be empty (and non-editable). Also the dialog will show the  message "Keystore was tampered with, or password as incorrect" on top instead of the message "Enter key password".

If you are absolutely sure that you have the correct password and are using the correct keystore, then the only other explanation I can think of is that something has gone wrong with the keystore. Perhaps you saved it as ASCII in your CVS/SVN?

Comment: this is exactly what my problem was. Because its such a routine i completely missed the error message - "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect".

Comment: Oh my god, what a life saver! Thank you for you answer, you saved me from a lot of pain :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and after a long time of searching I managed to fix it.

**WHAT CAUSES THE ERROR?**

That error occurs when

1. You have typed wrong the keystore password
2. Your keystore has been damaged for some reason

**MY CASE SCENARIO**

In my case I used a **correct** password, which means that my keystore was damaged.

Everything worked fine since I renamed my application, and I changed the location of the keystore and apk. Then I got confused about where the keystore and the apk is, in that confusion I might have **replaced the keystore with the new apk** which damaged the keystore but I cant be 100% sure.

**HOW DID I FIXED IT**

The fix was simple. For win7: **Locate the "original" keystore that was damaged, right click on it, choose Properties, Previous Versions, choose an earlier version when the keystore was ok and click Restore**

When you click on Previous Versions you have to **give it some time** (mine took like 30sec). If still nothing happens then the keystore you are trying to restore might not be the "original", it might be a copy or something.

(I say "original" because I tried other ways to fix this error and I had to make copies of the keystore, so to be sure **use the original damaged keystore**)

**IF STILL NOTHING HAPPENS**

If you did the above and still Eclipse does not show the alias you might have changed the directory of the keystore as I did.

**If you have changed your keystore directory you should do all the above and then place it at the previous directory where it worked, otherwise eclipse will not locate the alias !**

To see if your keystore works without using Eclipse  you can use the KeyTool.

1. Locate you Java JRE bin folder where keytool.exe should be (mine was C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin)
2. Make a copy of your keystore there (to simplify things)
3. Open a command line and run those commands

*cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin*

*keytool -list -keystore "yourkeystorename"*

Then you should be asked for the keystore password, if not the keystore is still damaged which means that restore did not work.

*Remember to make copies of the working keystores every time you publish an application and you know the keystore works fine.*

Answer (score 1):

i think you entered a wrong password...please make sure that password is currect...otherwise the alias name is not shown in dropdown list..

or

May be your keystore location is changed...

Answer (score 0):

if you remember the name, try to introduce it as a new one, it will force the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue, My case I wrongly entered the password for first time, so it didnt populate the alias list.

If you remember the password, just Clean All projects -> Built and continue from first. It worked and successfully uploaded to Google play.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I had the same issue, and realised that all I was missing was where I put the key as I stored it in another folder. When I tried to update the APK it didnt show the key alias cause there was no key in the folder I was trying to read it from. So I realised I had saved it in another folder. Once I relocated the correct folder the Key Alias showed up and was all good from there.